# Issue with creating the instance of the model in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing simple app in EmberJS and trying to do some simple objects creation in the console. I'm trying to create `PageModel` and then retrieve it from the store (I use localstorage). Unfortunately it doesn't succeeded.

```
// creates the PageModel instance
page = store.createRecord(App.PageModel)
Class {id: "i1i67", store: Class, container: Container, _changesToSync: Object, _deferredTriggers: Array[0]…}

// tries to retrieve the object from the storage
store.find('page', page.get('id'))
// but doesn't work
Class {__ember1413471577603: null, __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object, constructor: function, _super: function…}
```

Can anyone is able to help with ?

Comment: What does "doesn't succeeded" mean?

Comment: `find` doesn't return the App.PageModel instance with given `id`

Comment: Are there errors in the console?  What does `find` return?

Comment: `Class {__ember1413471577603: null, __nextSuper: undefined, __ember_meta__: Object, constructor: function, _super: function…}`
which I interpret as blank collection/result.

Comment: `createRecord` doesn't save it, page.save() after creation

Comment: Unfortunately after `page.save()` it doesn't cause that object is visible by `store.find(id)`

Answer (score 0):

If your model is called `PageModel`, then I'd expect the store to call it `page_model`.  It is unusual to call your model `ThingModel`- more common is `Thing`.  However, this works too:

```
store.find(App.PageModel, page.get('id'))
```